# compare rows among each other of same values in the columns and generate a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like below and want to compare the rows among each others. Afterwards it should count how often two rows have in all the columns the value one.

```
object |A|B|C|D|E
101     1 1 1 1 1
102     1 0 1 0 0
103     0 1 0 1 1
```

what I want to see (I put NaN since comparing the same row with itself does not make sense).

```
   101 | 102 | 103
101 NaN   2     3
102 2   NaN     0
103 3     0     NaN
```

Right now I only do that but that's making it only for the columns, and not rows:

```
data=pd.DataFrame()#dummy
matrix=data.T.dot(data.T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `dot`

```
s=df.iloc[:,1:].values
s.dot(s.T)
Out[308]: 
array([[5, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 0, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

---

Then we recreate the dataframe

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(s.dot(s.T),index=df.object,columns=df.object)
newdf=newdf.astype(float)
newdf.values[[np.arange(len(newdf))]*2]=np.nan # mask the diagonal to nan
newdf
Out[312]: 
object  101  102  103
object               
101     NaN  2.0  3.0
102     2.0  NaN  0.0
103     3.0  0.0  NaN
```

Comment: that solves it thank you, I would be also glad for any advice to improve my skills to solve this kind of problems

Comment: dot is counting the same numbers, which command is looking for the differences (so for 101 and 102 the value in the cells would be 3) ?

Comment: dot is matrix multiple @annstudent93 it will multiple each row of the matrix to each column